# powershell скрип для создания пользователей

Tags: powershell

Нужно создать 20 пользователей скриптом, логин должен быть НазваниеГруппы_№пользователя_@kik.ru а пароль это логин но в обратном порядке

Должно как то так получится логин sel_1@kik.ru пароль ur.kik@1_les Я тут написал конечно скрипт но в нем много ошибок

```
$org=″OU=sel,DC=kik,DC=ru″
$count=1..20
foreach ($i in $count)
{ New-AdUser -Name ("sel"+$i+"@kik.ru") -Path $org -Enabled $True -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true `
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString pas() -AsPlainText -force) -passThru }

function pas([String] $pas){
$t = "IT"+$i+"@kazan.wsr";

for (int i=1; i -le $t.Lenght; i++)
{
$pas[i]=$t[$t.Lenght-i];
}

}
```